# How can we detect whether forward or redirect prefix is present in string url?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How can we detect whether forward or redirect prefix is present in url string?
Let's assume that redirect is in request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "mappingUrl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String doSmth(final HttpServletRequest request){
        String redirectUrl = request.getAttribute("redirectUrl");
        if (containsPrefix(redirectUrl)){
            return redirectUrl;
        }
        else {
            return "redirect:" + redirectUrl;
        }
}
```

Are there any out-of-the-box way to check containsPrefix?

Comment: What about Regex ? Or a simple `String.startWith(String)` since you are looking for a prefix

Comment: You are trying to check for prefix or want to know whether this method is getting called by redirect or forward?